# Redirect to intended page after login in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently developing Cart page of my e-commerce application, If i click on checkout button it will popup Login modal, After login I need to go to Checkout page, But Any time I logged in It will redirect me to Home page. Is there Any easy way to do that in Laravel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `intended()` helper in your login controller

```
redirect()->intended();
```

Comment: Can you send me documentation link where they discussed about intended() helper.

Comment: I could not find it on Laravel' website, but you people have disscussed about in Laracast.com

Comment: @Abhilash.k.p documentation for intended : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users